# wp-cron wrong spawn with action scheduler

Tags: wordpress, server, cron

I deactivated the wp-cron from the wp-config file via
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
and activated the reading of the wp-cron.php file through the server by setting it to 2 minutes

I then inserted a scheduled action using the action scheduler plugin https://actionscheduler.org/, everything runs correctly if the scheduled action is handled by action started via Async Request but it can happen that the action is scheduled by action started via WP Cron causing my scheduled action to no longer run correctly. how can i do?

I expect the scheduled action to always be executed by action started via Async Request